# Angular splice hiding error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, splice

I have the following `ng-repeat`:

```
    <li class="list-group-item module" draggable="true" style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;" ng-repeat="module in academyModules">
    <span class="pull-left media-xs draggable" style="margin-top: 5px;"><i
            class="fa fa-sort text-muted fa m-r-sm"></i></span>

    <div class="clear">

        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-10">
            <button class="btn btn-s-xs btn-rounded m-r-lg" ng-class="module.module_type.color"
                    style="padding:  2px 10px; min-width: 90px;">{{module.module_type.name}}
            </button>
            <span class="text text-muted">Modul</span>
        </div>
                        <span class="pull-right">
                            <a class="btn btn-md pull-right no-padder" title="" ng-click="deleteModule(module);"><i
                                    class="fa fa-times text-danger text"></i></a>
                        </span>

        <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-11">
            <div class="input-group m-b">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="changeModule(module)" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#modal_select_module" style="font-size: 10px;"
                            type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Skift modul
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!-- /btn-group -->
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{module.module.name}}" style="height: 27px"
                       disabled="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Within this i have a delete function:

```
ng-click="deleteModule(module);"
```

That calls the following function:

```
    $scope.deleteModule = function(module)
{
    $http({
        url: api.getUrl('deleteAcademyModule',$scope.current_id),
        method: "POST",
        data: {module_id:module.module_id, academy_id: $scope.current_id}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    });
    $scope.academyModules.splice(module,1);
}
```

The problem is that when i press delete the correct module is deleted from the database using the `$http` however the wrong item is being removed / hidden from the list:

[image]

Now lets say that i delete the middle item (the red aka Test)

The list will look like this:

[image]

As you can see it removed the item above from the list however the id sent to the database matches the middle object so when i refresh my page i have the following (correct) view:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what the hell is going on?

Comment: can you provide a demo? Where is you `current_id` set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**

If you want the index of your current element within a `ng-repeat`, you need to use the variable `$index`.

So you can replace :

`ng-click="deleteModule(module);"`

by

`ng-click="deleteModule($index);"`

Your `splice` method will do the correct job.

**Solution 2 :**

You can change method in your controller to retrieve element index :

```
var pos = $scope.academyModules.indexOf(module);
if (-1 !== pos) {
  $scope.academyModules.splice(pos, 1);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm with index :p

Answer (score 1):

Check:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```
array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])
```

You should try to pointing module by index:

array.splice(1, 1); // Delete from 1st position, one element

(Change first param for you var, currently called "module", but pass index)

Answer (score 1):

module is an object if I'm not mistaken, try putting its index as parameter of the splice function instead :

```
   $scope.academyModules.splice($scope.academyModules.indexOf(module),1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code `$scope.academyModules.splice(module,1);` you module does not represent an integer.

Maybe you can do this instead:

`ng-click="deleteModule(module, $index);"`

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.deleteModule = function(module, pos)
{
    $http({
        url: api.getUrl('deleteAcademyModule',$scope.current_id),
        method: "POST",
        data: {module_id:module.module_id, academy_id: $scope.current_id}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    });
    $scope.academyModules.splice(pos,1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because of the way splice() works. The first argument is the index where the splice begins but the area you are "splicing" will not include the element located at that position in the array since the indices start at zero. The following code will NOT splice of the first item in the array. I assume you are populating your list from bottom to top and that is why the top item is being deleted (because sequentially it comes after the item you are trying to delete).

```
var list = [1,2,3,4];
```

list.splice(1, 1);

console.log(list);

http://codepen.io/nhmaggiej/pen/LEqKvm